# Yodlee- Transaction Storage

Tags: yodlee

I'm creating a Fin App which uses Yodlee service to access user's transaction information. I want to display this information to user each time when they log in. So I'm wondering if my app should store this transaction information in the database after the initial successful API query or should the app query the API each time the user log in. I can see either way works but I'm wondering what's the standard way Fin App developer uses. And if so, is what's the advantage/disadvantage?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, there are two ways to display the transactions to the user.

**1.** Query the API each time and then display the transactions to the user.

**Pros:**

- You need not to have a DB infrastructure to store the transactions.
- Easy to implement.

**Cons:**

- You need to dependent on Yodlee every time you want to display transactions to the user.
- Depending upon how many number of day's/transactions you display to the user, may cause issues as response would be huge depending upon the number of transactions user will have.
- In case due to some network issue your App won't be able to connect with Yodlee then better User Experience could be questioned.

**2.** Query and store the transactions and then display it from your local database.

**Pros:**

- You can query and store the user's transactions and even do analytic on that.
- Shouldn't cause any issue if user has much more transactions, you can put customer queries to display the transactions.
- You could use Procedural Data Extracts to keep your data in sync with Yodlee i.e., have your latest data.

**Cons:**

- You need to implement your own transactions reconciliation logic.
- Have to setup DB infrastructure.

These are the high level pros and cons of both the approaches, while it depends upon what solution you are building and how/what options you will be going to provide users to see the transactions in the App.